# How do I skip a value using the while loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <head>LOOPS</head>
        <h1 id="string"></h1>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
              let w = 10;
              while (w <= 15) {
                console.log(w);

                if (w == 12) {
                  continue;
                }
                w++;
              }        
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This creates an infinite loop, But I'm trying to skip 12, if I remove the increment it doesn't display at all.

Comment: `continue` means "skip the rest of this loop and head straight to the next iteration". The only thing you are skipping in your loop is the `w++` part, which is why you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase `w` value before you do the skipping, one method is to do it inside the `while` condition:

```js
let w = 9;
while(++w<=15){

    if(w==12){
        continue;
    }
    console.log(w)
};
```

Comment: I'd argue the best way is using a regular for-loop. Having an increment and comparison in the same expression isn't usually considered good practice.

Comment: @Ivar I agree, poor wording :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that code:

```js
let w = 10;
while (w <= 15) {
  console.log(w);
  if (w == 12) {
    continue;
  }
  w++; // JS never access to this line after printing 10, 11 and 12
}
```

because `continue` statement **jumps over** one iteration in the loop. so JS never access to increment `w` variable, so it will *infinite-loop* just printing *12* and continue printing it without increment `w`; to solve it just increment it before you check if condition:

```js
let w = 10;
while (w <= 15) {
  console.log(w);
  w++;
  if (w == 12) {
    continue;
  }
}
```